# How is the start time for Incremental Analysis Database Sync job set

Tags: tfs

The "Incremental Analysis Database Sync" job (one of the jobs that TFS uses to update the [SQL Server Analysis Service cube](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244706.aspx)) only has an interval that can be set as to how frequently the job is run (via the [IncrementalProcessIntervalSeconds setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458305.aspx))

Is there a way to specify the initial time that this job runs?

I'd like to ensure that the job schedule doesn't coincide with hourly backups.

Comment: The update of the Cube is made of one Full Processing (where you can set the start time) and then many incremental updates (where you can set the interval). If I understand your question you want to make sure there's an interval where it's guarantied that there's NO full or incremental updates ?

Comment: I think so. I know you can set the initial time for Full Processing. Is Incremental offset from that (which would answer my question), or does it have some other way of determining the initial start time? If I know it will always run on the hour, then I could schedule backups to occur on the 1/2 hour so they don't overlap (as I've seen errors from the sync jobs that seem to relate to backup jobs happening at the same time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your answer [here](http://estebanfg.blogspot.fr/2011/02/controlling-data-warehouse-refresh-in.html)
Also [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244694.aspx) on the MSDN is useful.

You have to call the ChangeSetting webmethod of the WebService with DailyFullProcessingTime as settingId and newValue a string of the DateTime you want to set.

Check the result by calling  GetSettingsResponse.